# R/S configuration of bridging carbon in bicyclic system

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

I am trying to figure out the R and S configuration of bridging carbons in bicyclic systems.

In the image, there are two bicyclic systems and depending on the position of the Br substituent, the R or S configuration of the bridging carbons change. How is the configuration actually determined? I don't understand how the prioritization works in this case, as two substituents are similar. Thus, the reason must be the adjacent stereocenter... But I am not able explain it properly.

[image]

Comment: If the two substituents were similar, that would be the end of the story. However, they are not. The first atoms might be similar, but then you have to go and compare the next atoms, and so on.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes I have compared the next atoms but at the third atom, the both substituents meet again as their third atom is the same. and from that point, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Are you sure the bridgehead carbons are stereogenic?

Comment: @Zhe Yes, because the solution to my exercise marked the carbons with R and S tags and when drawing these structures in ChemDraw, the R and S configurations were assigned automatically, too...

Comment: You should continue in _all_ directions at once, not just along the cycle.

Comment: To be sure, the carbons of two bis-methylene bridges are heterotopic because of their in-space relationship to the substitution, but again, does that matter? If you say yes, then you would also need to assign a configuration to the isolated methylene unit. That has two hydrogen atoms, but they are diastereotopic. But you're not claiming that that is a stereogenic center. Therefore, something is contradictory in your reasoning.

Comment: So the assignment of Chemdraw and the solution to our exercise is kind of confusing. I totally agree with you, that the two loops are identical, hence, defining R/S configurations does not make sense. Can you explain why the solution and chemdraw assign R and S? Or what exactly does the R/S at bridging carbon mean? I mean there must be a reason why it is written like this, mustn't it?

Comment: @Faded Giant  You wrote, "2,2-dimethylbicyclo[2.2.2]octane contains two pseudoasymmetric centers". I believe you are referring to the bridgehead carbons and that you are discussing 2,2-dimethyl, not 2-bromo, 2-methylbicyclo[2.2.2]octane. If so, then the bridgehead carbons are actually prochiral rather than pseudoasymmetric. Hence the lowercase "r" and "s" descriptors do not apply (pro-r or pro-s could be used in referring to the bridgehead carbons).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Several days ago I offered a solution to the R/S assignment of the bridgehead carbons of (1*R*,2*S*,4*R*)-2-bromo-2-methylbicyclo[2.2.2]octane **1**. During the middle of the night I realized that the method was faulty because the solution would not accommodate the (1*S*,2*R*,4*S*) enantiomer  **3** but would rather predict (1*R*,2*R*,4*R*) which clearly is a non-existent diastereomer. The shortcoming lay in not applying, in a heirarchical sense, [CIP rule 4b (RR/SS>RS/SR) over rule 5 (R>S)](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/CIP%20rules%20NEW.html).
Focusing on bromide **1**, the configuration of C<sub>2</sub> is "S" with Br>C<sub>1</sub>>C<sub>3</sub>>C<sub>9</sub>. Structure **2** is structure **1** from a different perspective to which we will refer during the ensuing discussion. To determine the configurations of the bridgehead carbons, C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>4</sub>, a digraph is the method of choice. In the "Digraph of C<sub>1</sub>" one starts at the non-duplicate atom C<sub>1</sub> and traces the six possible paths back to duplicate atoms C<sub>(1)</sub> that are each attached to three phantom atoms of atomic number zero. The vertical chain has the top priority while the hydrogen (not shown) at C<sub>1</sub> has the lowest priority. The two horizontal chains are mirror images as far as the atom connectivity is concerned and they must be assigned to the second and third priorities. In these chains C<sub>2</sub> has been predetermined as having the *S*-configuration. Locate C<sub>4</sub> in the left chain. It has the *R*-configuration because C<sub>3</sub>>C<sub>8</sub>>C<sub>5</sub>. Locate these atoms in structure **2** and convince yourself. [I use my hands. Point your right thumb from C<sub>4</sub> to H and your fingers will point from C<sub>3</sub> to C<sub>8</sub> to C<sub>5</sub>]. In the right hand chain C<sub>4</sub> has the *S*-configuration because C<sub>3</sub>>C<sub>5</sub>>C<sub>8</sub>. Check these priorities in structure **2**.
Now the left hand chain is designated as RS and the right hand chain as SS. Since RR/SS>RS/SR, the order of carbon atoms attached to non-duplicate C<sub>1</sub> is C<sub>2</sub>>C<sub>6</sub>>C<sub>7</sub>. Locate these atoms in structure **2** and convince yourself that C<sub>1</sub> does indeed have the *R*-configuration!
Look at "Digraph of C<sub>4</sub>". Now that you are versed in the method, the priorities around non-duplicate C<sub>4</sub> are C<sub>3</sub>>C<sub>8</sub>>C<sub>5</sub> because C<sub>3</sub>-chain>SS>RS>H. C<sub>4</sub> also is of the *R*-configuration! <*continued*>

[image]

The digraphs below confirm the assignments to the enantiomer **3** (**4**), (1*S*,2*R*,4*S*)-2-bromo-2-methylbicyclo[2.2.2]octane. I'll leave the analysis to the reader.

[image]

[image]