# Type of chirality in polycyclic compounds

Tags: stereochemistry, molecular-structure, isomers, chirality, heterocyclic-compounds

Ignoring whether or not this molecule could exist, is there a name for this type of chirality? This molecule's mirror image cannot be superimposed on itself but there are no chiral centres.

[image: Chiral boron compound]

Even though the bottom boron only has three substituents, the fact that they are all joined at the top gives it similar geometrical properties as if it were tetrahedral.

The InchI is InChI=1S/C4H8B2OS/c1-2-6-7-3-5(1)4-8-6/h1-4H2

Comment: Could it be an example of [Axial Chirality](https://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~gablek/CH334/Chapter5/MesoEtc.htm)? Where the axis is through the boron atoms?

Comment: how would boron exist in bridge head position? Is there a point in discussing chirality for something that may not even exist?

Comment: @safdar I'm sure you could substitute the atoms for something that could exist instead. I chose boron instead of carbon because trigonal planar atoms are inherently not stereocenters. The geometry is what matters.

Comment: Something like this? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136695/r-s-configuration-of-bridging-carbon-in-bicyclic-system

Comment: This atom's environment wouldn't be trigonal planar - pyramidalisation with ring strain. Still it's [planar chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_chirality).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/why-is-trans-cyclooctene-chiral

Comment: You don't need atoms or bonds to define chirality. Just the colored balls will suffice. I think it is an example closer to planar chirality: P or Rp.  (C-C-B-S). http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/planar.html

Comment: About "but there are no chiral centres" : not clear if you are aware, but they are not needed for a molecule to be chiral.